# How to Build Windows

Tags: java

When the program starts up, it will ask for four pieces of information from the user:

1. How many stories high the building will be
2. How many windows on each story
3. How wide each window will be
4. How tall each window will be

The program will set limits on each of these. The limits should be part of the question, like `how wide do you want the windows? (1-5).` If the user exceeds a limit, either above or below, a message should be output and the user should be queried again. This should occur as many times as is necessary to get a number within the limits. (As you can see the code below I am done with this part)

(I am having trouble with this part)the number and size of my windows should be controlled with loops. However I am not allowed to use massive "if" statements. The upper limits for each of the question should be included as a constant. For example, final int `MAXSTORIESHIGH=12;` If the constant is changed, my program should be able to handle the new limits without any other changes. What loops should I use to control the number and size of the windows?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BuildingAssign {

    public static void main (String [] args){

        int input;  

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.print("How many stories high the building will be? (1-5): ");
            input = in.nextInt();
        }while (input < 1 || input > 5);

        do {
            System.out.print("How many windows on each story? (1-10): ");
            input = in.nextInt();
        }while (input < 1 || input > 10);

        do {
            System.out.print("How wide each window will be? (3-5): ");
            input = in.nextInt();
        }while (input < 3 || input > 5);

        do {
            System.out.print("How tall each window will be? (4-6): ");
            input = in.nextInt();
        }while (input < 4 || input > 6);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems like you know how to do this already. Basically, you'd do the same thing you've been doing for the others, but instead of hardcoding in the parameters, you'd put the variable instead. For example,

```
final int MAXSTORIESHIGH= 12;
final int MINSTORIESHIGH = 1;
do {
        System.out.print("How many stories high the building will be? (1-5): ");
        input = in.nextInt();
    }while (input < MINSTORIESHIGH || input > MAXSTORIESHIGH);
```

If you wanted to change the max and min, you'd just change the variable's value.

Comment: Thanks, one more question. Where should I use print and println statements to draw a building on my console window. Let's say the high of the building will be 2 then it should show two storey building. Please click the link I provided if you don't know what I am talking about...http://i.imgur.com/C95mBfM.png  Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Haha, that's a lot more complex than your original question. I would skip doing that, because drawings to the console are a lot more annoying than you would expect, they don't look that good, and don't have any way to export to an app. I would just learn a graphical interface for the actual drawing , which luckily java is very good at. The Java2D API is very nice and one of my personal favorites. :)

Comment: If you still want to go for it, I can give you some tips. 

My approach would be to loop through each row of the building, and look to see what to draw. If it's a roof or floor you'd draw

`********`

if it's a window edge, you'd draw
`* *** *` where `***` is repeated for every window, and three is assuming the width is three.
if it's a window center, you'd draw
`* *  * *` where the space in the middle is the width.

Comment: Because it doesn't look like many others are going to answer this question as I already did, and you ALSO went ahead and asked a follow up question, I ask that you accept my answer?